# Проблемы с Billboard шейдером

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры, hlsl, vertex-shader

Делаю Billboard shader для Baldi мода на Unity (для полного отказа от Billboard скрипта). Нашел [шейдер](https://gist.github.com/kaiware007/8ebad2d28638ff83b6b74970a4f70c9a) в котором был такой метод:

```
float3 vpos = mul((float3x3)unity_ObjectToWorld, input.vertex.xyz);
float4 worldCoord = float4(unity_ObjectToWorld._m03, unity_ObjectToWorld._m13, unity_ObjectToWorld._m23, 1);
float4 viewPos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_V, worldCoord) + float4(vpos, 0);
float4 outPos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_P, viewPos);
```

Поставил это в vertex шейдер, и вроде работает, однако иногда спрайты просто исчезают с определенных ракурсов.

Видео: https://youtu.be/0ut6lJbtpec

Кто нибудь сталкивался с похожей проблемой?

Answer (score 0):

Поменял формулу, все заработало.

```
o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_P, 
 mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MV, float4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
 + float4(input.vertex.x, input.vertex.y, 0.0, 0.0)
 * float4(_ScaleX, _ScaleY, 1.0, 1.0));
```